# Alterar a qualidade do vídeo online?

Tags: php

Como sites como Youtube e Facebook oferecem diferentes qualidades para os vídeos upados? Existe alguma ferramenta/código especifico para alterar a qualidade dos vídeos, ou os mesmos codificam e salvam os arquivos de vídeo em diferentes formatos? 360p, 480p, 720p, 1020p ... Como funciona essa questão?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quando você envia um vídeo para o YouTube ele detecta a qualidade da versão enviada, o vídeo enviado será a maior qualidade disponível, as qualidades inferiores serão renderizadas pelo YouTube.

Por padrão, por questão de performance (e armazenamento) o YouTube irá compactar os vídeos e pode alterar a qualidade. *Inclusive por isso o Vimeo tem destaque por ter maior qualidade de vídeo, uma vez que possui menor compactação (e por isso geralmente os mesmos 1080p demora 10 vezes mais para carregar no Vimeo em relação ao YouTube).*

Seu pergunta inclui a tag de "ffmpeg", no qual pode ser usado para isso. :)

### **Compactando via CLI com ffmpeg:**

> Irei usar o CMD mas você pode executar isso usando o exec() do PHP.

Para exemplo estou usando este vídeo: https://pixabay.com/pt/videos/p%C3%B4r-do-sol-campo-paisagem-5933/

**Pegando a "resolução" atual:**

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "Sunset - 5933.mp4"
```

Isso irá retornar:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'Sunset - 5933.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    encoder         : Lavf56.4.101
  Duration: 00:00:13.44, start: 0.021016, bitrate: 5006 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 5003 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
```

Uma alternativa melhor é usar o ffprobe, [veja esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684015/how-can-i-get-the-resolution-width-and-height-for-a-video-file-from-a-linux-co).

Entretanto através do `1920x1080` já sabe que é 1080p.

**Tornando 1080p em 720p:**

```
ffmpeg.exe -i "Sunset - 5933.mp4" -vcodec libopenh264 -s 1280x720 -aspect 1280:720 "Sunset - 720.mp4"
```

Agora você terá dois arquivos, um para 1080p e outro para 720p. O `-vcodec` é o codec de vídeo, você deve usar o `ffmpeg.exe -i` para ver quais bibliotecas estão compiladas, procure por `libopenh264` ou por `libx264` você possui. O `-s` é a dimensão do arquivo e o `-aspect` é a proporção.

*Você também pode "renderizar" o áudio também para isso poderá usar o `-acodec` para definir um codec de áudio, o mais comum é o `libmp3lame` e poderá então mudar os bitrates e afins. Caso contrário, por padrão o áudio continuará idêntico.*

**Atenção:**

O `vcodec` mais comum é o `libx264`, porém ele está na licença de `GPL` o que pode não ser muito bom para algumas situações, principalmente para softwares proprietários (não-abertos). Eles oferecem uma licença comercial também, que creio eu não seja GPL. Por essa razão eu utilizo (como mencionado no exemplo) o `vcodec` de `libopenh264` ele está sobre licença `BSD` [(veja aqui)](https://github.com/cisco/openh264), sendo mais livre e ainda gratuito. Porém ele tem menos recursos e menos usados, inclusive muitas distribuições padrões do ffmpeg não incluem o `libopenh264`. O ffmpeg em geral está sobre LGPL, que é mais livre. *No caso do LGPL o seu software deve fazer um "link" com o ffmpeg, sendo softwares ainda distintos.*

Comment: WoW Obrigado cara, vou estudar um pouco mais sobre ffmpeg e ffprobe pois precisarei deles logo logo, vlw pela resposta completa

Answer (score -4):

Quando você assiste um vídeo no Youtube, você está fazendo o download de um arquivo, então a qualidade identifica o arquivo que você esta baixando, logo para cada qualidade, existe um arquivo diferente. Por isso que as vezes, quando o vídeo tem qualidade ruim ele possui apenas uma resolução.

Comment: Sua "resposta" não responde a pergunta, ao meu ver. A pergunta é justamente de como o YouTube faz para criar "cada arquivo". Quem "upa" o vídeo apenas envia uma qualidade (ex. 1080p), o YouTube gera o 360p. A pergunta, pelo que entendi, é justamente de como o YouTube gera o 360p a partir do 1080p.

Comment: "Existe alguma ferramenta/código especifico para alterar a qualidade dos vídeos, ou os mesmos codificam e salvam os arquivos de vídeo em diferentes formatos?" Essa foi a pergunta, e a mesma foi respondida.